# How to start a service even when the app is not open

Tags: android, firebase, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Here I am creating a chat app. In this app I want to load data from firebase realtime database whenever user switch on his internet or connects his phone to wifi no matter whether the app is open or not. I am doing this using service and broadcast. But I don't know why its not working. The method of fetching data is working properly as I have checked it in another activity.  Kindly checkout my codes below

I have registered my broadcast and service in menifest file as

```
<service android:name=".broadcasts.receiveMsgService" android:exported="true"/>
    <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.receiveChattersBroadcast"
    android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My broadcast file

```
public class receiveChattersBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Check the action of the intent
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || 
  action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        // Start the background service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, receiveMsgService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

My service file

```
public class receiveMsgService extends Service {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyForegroundService";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");

    // Load the messages from Firebase
    loadMessagesFromFirebase();
    
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void loadMessagesFromFirebase(){
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference refernec;

   // chatrecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.fragAllChatRecycler);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    refernec = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    refernec.keepSynced(true);
    ArrayList<chatterModal2> modals = new ArrayList();
    SharedPreferencelogin session = new SharedPreferencelogin(getApplicationContext());
    String userFireId = session.getFireId();
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    database.getReference().child("chatters").addValueEventListener(new 
 ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    chatterModal2 modal = snapshot1.getValue(chatterModal2.class) ;

                    String receiverId = modal.getRecieverId();
                    String sender = modal.getSenderId();

                   
                    if(receiverId.trim().equals(userFireId) || 
  sender.equals(userFireId)) {
                        modals.add(modal);
                        String addResult = db.addChatter(modal.getRecieverId(), 
   modal.getSenderId(), modal.getMsg(), modal.getUnseen(), modal.getProId(), 
    String.valueOf(modal.getTime()));



                    }else{
                        //do nothing
                    }

                   
                }
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    
     }
   }
```

I have not mentioned this service and broadcast any where else. Do I have to mention it or call it in any activity? Please tell me what's wrong

Comment: Maybe it not working because CONNECTIVITY_ACTION deprecated and not recommended to use in the manifest. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: In general, i think your code is not optimized. Your idea with check connection may be working for nothing without the result of new messages. I suggest using FirebaseMessagingService to get information about new messages

Comment: What I can use in the place of CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ?

Comment: My service is working fine as I have checked it by calling it directly in MainActivity . But it is not working thorugh broadcast. May be my broadcast is not being call.